# Read words from input, store in lists, then count the vowels and send count to file

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to read words from input and store each word in a list. Then I want to count the vowels in each word and write the count into a file.

Here is what I did so far:

```
readWord(InStream,W) :- get0(InStream,Char),
                        checkCharAndReadRest(Char,Chars,InStream)
%                       ,program(Chars),
                        ,checkChars(Chars)  ,
                         atom_chars(W,Chars).

%checkChars(Chars):- member([97,101,105,111,117] , Chars).
checkChars(Chars):- member(97, Chars).
checkCharAndReadRest(10,[],_) :- !. % Return
checkCharAndReadRest(32,[],_) :- !. % Space
checkCharAndReadRest(-1,[],_) :- !. % End of Stream
checkCharAndReadRest(end_of_file,[],_) :- !.
checkCharAndReadRest(Char,[Char|Chars],InStream) :- 
     get0(InStream,NextChar),
checkCharAndReadRest(NextChar,Chars,InStream).

writeWord(end_of_file).
writeWord(X) :- write(X),nl.

readFile :- 
     open('c:/sample.txt', read, In), 
     repeat, 
     readWord(In,W),
     writeWord(W),
     W == end_of_file, 
     !, 
     close(In).

member(X, [ _ | Z]):-member(X, Z).
member(X, [X | _ ]):-increment(0,N).

increment(N0,N):- N is N0+1,write(N).

%program(Chars) :-
%open('e:/outputfile.txt',write, Stream),
%write(Stream,X),
%close(Stream).
```

The words are stored perfectly in lists, but I don't know how to count them each time
and send the count to a file.

Comment: One of several problems is that you're redefining a built-in predicate (`member`) which isn't a generally a good idea. In addition, your version of `member` calls `increment` with a singleton parameter `N` which isn't in the parameter list of `member` so it doesn't go anywhere. Also note that `increment` is only ever called with parameters `0, N` so it will always write a `1`.

Comment: So the problems you're _actually_ facing, are a) counting the vowels in the words and b) writing to a file. My suggestion would be to turn this into two separate questions, _showing just the code that's relevant_.